# Counting Pattern Occurence in Pandas DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column where each row contains a list. I'm wondering what the most efficient way / best practice would be to identify patterns from the column of lists - for example, the average number of rejects before accepts. (See example below)

```
    sequence_of_selection
0   Accept,Reject,Reject,Reject,Reject,Accept,Reje...
1   Accept,Reject,Reject,Reject,Reject,Reject,Reje...
2   Reject,Accept,Accept,Reject,Reject,Reject,Acce...
3   Accept,Reject,Accept,Accept,Accept,Accept,Reje...
4   Reject,Accept,Reject,Accept,Reject,Reject,Acce...
```

I can convert the data to strings and split them or search for substrings within the string and so on, but I would prefer to seek a more efficient way as Python strings are immutable.

Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

[Jupyter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt0kC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This is a really great question!*** I would like to emphasize the power in the temporal spacing of events – there is so much insight into behavior and predictability based on sequences like the one posted. Considering that, I wrote a long answer to hopefully explain some core principles of data manipulation.

**1. Create a custom function to execute your calculations:** 
*(Pretend you're applying to just one list – I'd actually suggest extracting a single list while debugging or testing)*

```py
def event_metrics(my_list, look_for = "Accept", exclude_zeros=True, simple=True):
    """
    Simple mode:
        Returns the average number of `items` before `look_for` 

    Non-Simple mode:
        Returns a dictionary with the mean, median, and max number of `items`
        before `look_for` 

    --
    my_list: a list of values

    look_for: An item in the list which constitutes the "event"
              Example: "accept" from a list of "accept" and "reject"

    exclude_zeros: exclude metrics for when `look_for` occurs back to back

    simple: operate in simple mode or non-simple mode

    """

    # Instantiate a counter list
    my_counter = []
    n = 0

    # Loop through the list
    for x in my_list:

        # If a match, add n to the list and reset
        if x==look_for:
            my_counter.append(n)
            n=0

        # Otherwise, continue
        else:
            n+=1

    # Sometimes you might want to append the final n at conclusion of the loop
    # You could do that with the following code:
    # if x!=look_for:
    #     my_counter.append(n)


    # You may not want to include back-to-back events
    if exclude_zeros:
        my_counter = [x for x in my_counter if x>0]

    # You can return a specific metric such as mean
    if simple:
        return np.mean(my_counter)

    # Or you can pass several metrics as a dictionary and convert to a series
    my_metrics = {
        "mean":np.mean(my_counter),
        "median":np.median(my_counter),
        "max":np.max(my_counter)
    }
    return my_metrics
```

**2. Apply this custom function to your df:**

- **Simple mode:** returns an array of single values – treat like a new column.
- **Non-Simple mode:** returns an array of dictionaries – convert to multiple columns using `pd.to_Series`. Add to original `df` using `pd.merge`.

```py
# Simple Mode
df["sequence_of_selection"].apply(event_metrics, simple=True)

# Non-Simple Mode
temp_df = df["sequence_of_selection"].apply(event_metrics, simple=False)\
            .apply(pd.Series)\  # Convert to its own df
            .add_prefix("rej_") # Add a prefix to your column names

df.merge(temp_df,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they are lists, you can get the `index` of `'Accept'` and then take the average of those indexes. If the index is 0, the first item in the list is `'Accept'`, so there are zero`'Reject'` before it, and so forth.

```
df['sequence_of_selection'].apply(lambda x: x.index('Accept')).mean()
```